# MySQL / Mariadb - Select * from Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, mariadb

I am attempting to use [UF Dashbuilder](https://github.com/kiegroup/appformer/tree/r7.5.0.Final) which adds syntax to my SQL query and I don't know how to correct it.

The call that works is similar to:

```
call database.report ('1234', 'txt');
```

Dashbuilder turns it into this which does not work:

```
 SELECT * FROM (call database.report ('1234', 'txt');) AS `dbSQL` LIMIT 1
```

I could also use the code below from the end of the stored procedure to store the results in a table and then `SELECT * FROM TABLE` in Dashbuilder, but I don't know how to store the results in a table (dynamic number of columns).

**Can you please tell me how I can make a stored procedure work with SELECT * added or how I can store the results from this code in a table?**

```
  SET @sql = NULL;
   SET SESSION GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = 1000000;  -- default is 1024
   SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(question = ''', REPLACE(question,"'", "\\'"), ''', answer, NULL)) AS ''', REPLACE(question,"'", "\\'"), ''''
         )
      ) INTO @sql
      FROM tmp2;

      SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, datestamp, ', @sql, ' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id');

      -- SELECT @sql;   

      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**UPDATE 1.
  COMMENTS TO ANSWER 1:**
Results from original @SQL:

```
`SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, datestamp, ', @sql, ' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id');`


SELECT id, datestamp, MAX(IF(question = '1. Our records show that you got care from the provider named below in the last 6 months. {Provider}.  Is that right?', answer, NULL)) 
   AS '1. Our records show that you got care from the provider named below in the last 6 months. {Provider}.  Is that right?',
   MAX(IF(question = '2. Is this the provider you usually see if you need a check-up, want advice about a health problem, or get sick or hurt?', answer, NULL)) 
   AS '2. Is this the provider you usually see if you need a check-up, want advice about a health problem, or get sick or hurt?',
   MAX(IF(question = 'Area', answer, NULL)) AS 'Area',MAX(IF(question = 'Encounter', answer, NULL)) AS 'Encounter' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id
```

Results from @SQL:

**ERROR: Error Code: 1166. Incorrect column name '1. Our records show that you got care from the provider named below in the last 6 months. {Provider}'**

I guess there is a character that it does not like such as the single quotes?

```
SET @tableName = 'myreport';
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', @tableName, ' AS SELECT id, datestamp, ', @sql, ' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id');


CREATE TABLE myreport AS SELECT id, datestamp, MAX(IF(question = '1. Our records show that you got care from the provider named below in the last 6 months. {Provider}.  Is that right?', answer, NULL)) 
   AS '1. Our records show that you got care from the provider named below in the last 6 months. {Provider}.  Is that right?',
   MAX(IF(question = '2. Is this the provider you usually see if you need a check-up, want advice about a health problem, or get sick or hurt?', answer, NULL)) 
   AS '2. Is this the provider you usually see if you need a check-up, want advice about a health problem, or get sick or hurt?',
   MAX(IF(question = 'Area', answer, NULL)) AS 'Area',MAX(IF(question = 'Encounter', answer, NULL)) AS 'Encounter' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id
```

**UPDATE 2:
THIS WORKS!!!  THANKS!**
I have to reduce the length of the column name as shown below.  Then I can run the stored procedure twice per day and select * from this table in Dashbuilder.

```
CREATE TABLE myreport AS SELECT id, datestamp, MAX(IF(question = '1. Our records show that you got care from the provider named below in the last 6 months. {Provider}.  Is that right?', answer, NULL)) 
   AS '1.',
   MAX(IF(question = '2. Is this the provider you usually see if you need a check-up, want advice about a health problem, or get sick or hurt?', answer, NULL)) 
   AS '2.',
   MAX(IF(question = 'Area', answer, NULL)) AS 'Area',MAX(IF(question = 'Encounter', answer, NULL)) AS 'Encounter' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id
```

**UPDATE 3: This works! Thanks!**

```
   SET @t = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', survey_report );
   PREPARE stmt FROM @t;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

   SET @sql = NULL;
   SET SESSION GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = 1000000;  -- default is 1024
   SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT(  
            'MAX(IF(question = ''', REPLACE(question,"'", "\\'"), ''', answer, NULL)) AS ''', REPLACE(udf_clean_column_name(15, udf_remove_tags(question)),"'", "\\'"), ''''
         )
      ) INTO @sql
      FROM tmp2;

      SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', survey_report, ' AS SELECT id, datestamp, ipaddr, ', @sql, ' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id');

      -- SELECT @sql;

      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   

   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `survey_lookup`;
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp`;
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp2`;
```

Mysql Function to remove spaces, etc. from the column names.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `udf_clean_column_name`(col_name_len INT, str varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(200)
    BEGIN
       SET str = SUBSTRING(str,1,col_name_len);
       SET str = TRIM(str);
       SET str = Replace(str,' ','_');
       SET str = Replace(str,'-','');
       SET str = Replace(str,'?','');
       SET str = Replace(str,',','');
       SET str = Replace(str,'.','');
       RETURN str;
    END;
```

Mysql function to remove tags (I don't recall where I got this function).

```
CREATE FUNCTION `udf_remove_tags`(Dirty varchar(4000))
RETURNS varchar(4000)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
      DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
        WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
          BEGIN
            SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
            SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
            IF iLength > 0 THEN
              BEGIN
                SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
                set Dirty = Replace(Dirty,'&nbsp;',''); #No space between & and nbsp;
                set Dirty = Replace(Dirty,'\r','');
                set Dirty = Replace(Dirty,'\n','');
              END;
            END IF;
          END;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN Dirty;
    END;
```

Comment: Is this you? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dashbuilder-usage/Lq-pLt-BWLQ/7wZWRaCPBAAJ or is it someone else with the same problem?

Comment: The second message from Kevin is mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any mention of stored procedures in the UF DashBuilder documentation, so it looks like they don't have a way around this.

You can create a table from a `SELECT` query. If you omit the column specifications, they'll be derived automatically from the select list of the query.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', tableName, ' AS
    SELECT id, datestamp, ', @sql, ' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks.  The previous version of Dashbuilder allowed stored procedures.  I was unable to find where they add the syntax in the code.   I got this error:   `Error Code: 1166. Incorrect column name '1. Our records show that you got care from the provider named below in the last 6 months.`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this library, but maybe there are different calls to return just one row or all rows. The wrapper they're adding is designed to restrict the result to a single row.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I added more text to the original question because this box did not offer enough space.